# How to do 2 commands at the same time using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have seen another question similar to mine on here. The answer was to use the `&` sign to run both commands in one line. But that was for two different commands, the two commands I am trying to are `goto` and `echo`.

When I try putting an `&` sign after what I want to `echo`, it thinks that I want to `echo` the `&` sign. So then I try and put the `&` sign after the `goto EXAMPLETEXT` and it believes I want to go to a place in my batch file called `EXAMPLETEXT &`. The commands don't know when to deviate from their command to the next one.

If you want to know what context I am using this for or why I need to use this, the reason is is that I am asking a question, `set /p answer=Are you ready to begin?:` I then have, `if %answer% == Ready goto begin` and `if %answer == Not ready goto NOTREADY` and `if %answer% == yes goto begin` and so on.

Then at the end of all the specified answer choices acceptable, I want to put, `if not defined %answer% echo Not an acceptable answer & goto READYTOBEGIN?` (sends back to the question so that they can re-answer.) But of course because of the specified reasons that will not work for me.

Comment: Why does it absolutely have to be on one line? If you use parentheses, you can have both commands in a code block and you don't need to worry about `&`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `if exist` use the variableNAME, not the variable itself (no `%`)

Your line

```
if not defined %answer% echo Not an acceptable answer & goto READYTOBEGIN?
```

is parsed (because `%answer%` is empty) as:

```
if not defined echo Not an acceptable answer & goto READYTOBEGIN?
```

`echo` is also not defined (probably), so the command to be executed is `Not` - which leads to an error "command not found".
If it **is** defined, there's no error, but that's not much better. Let's assume, the user entered `hello`, then the line gets parsed as:

```
if not defined hello echo Not an acceptable answer & goto READYTOBEGIN?
```

The variable `hello` is probably not defined, but it might be - so you have an unpredictable behaviour.

The correct syntax for your line would be:

```
if not defined answer echo Not an acceptable answer & goto READYTOBEGIN?
```

What do you do, when the user enters for example `qwertzui`? `answer` is defined, so the `echo` and `goto` are being ignored. Better omit the last `if` completeley and replace the line with just:

```
echo Not an acceptable answer & goto READYTOBEGIN?
```

so it fires, if `answer` is either not defined or didn't get catched with the previous `if`s